# Force Windows 10 to Honor Volume Level 1-5

Tags: windows-10, audio

How do I force Windows 10 to honor volume level 1?

The volume control adjusts by two units, anything less than six just outright mutes all audio. I might not be a mathematician though I'm pretty sure one, two, three, four and five are greater than zero.

Comment: This only happens to me when I let the volume media key to repeat. Going slowly, it goes in increments of `2`.

Comment: This may also be dependent on the specific hardware and drivers; on neither my Surface Pro 3 nor my Dell XPS 15 do I see this phenomenon.

Comment: Try replacing the Audio Driver.  I just tested  40 (where I keep it) to 0 in units of 1 all the way and back up to 40 in units of 1 all the way. Two different Lenovo laptops with two different audio hardware and drivers.